# Method not being called properly?! Calorie App

Tags: java, methods

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //making values easier to change and also create global variables for gym comparison

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("How many calories did you consume today?>> ");
    int actualIntake = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is your BMR?>> ");
    int BMR = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();

    //this method is what is expected with deficit
    calorieCalculation(actualIntake,BMR);
    //this is what you actually ate
    actualCalories(actualIntake,BMR);

    //gym with protein
        gym (30,40,50,100, actualIntake);
    }
    //testing method
    testingMeth(actualIntake);




    //What the user should be following
    public static int calorieCalculation(int actualIntake, int BMR){
        int calorieDifference = BMR - actualIntake;

        if (calorieDifference <= 0 ){
            calorieDifference = Math.abs (BMR - actualIntake);
            System.out.println("You have went over your deficit, well done fatty = " + calorieDifference);
        } else if (calorieDifference >= 0){
            System.out.println("Expected calorie deficit should be " + calorieDifference);
        }

        return calorieDifference;
    }

//What the user actually did
    public static int actualCalories (int actualIntake, int BMR ) {

        int deficitCalculation = actualIntake - BMR;
        if (actualIntake > BMR ) {
            System.out.println("You fat lard stop overeating you dumbass, " + "failed deficit of over " + deficitCalculation + " Calories.");

        } else if (actualIntake < BMR ) {
            System.out.println("Well done you created a deficit of " + deficitCalculation + " keep her going keep her movin." );
        }
        return deficitCalculation;
    }

//How much did you burn in the gym
    public static int gym (int treadMillCal, int rowingMachineCal, int weightsCal, int proteinShakeCal, int actualIntake) {

        int totalGym = ((treadMillCal + rowingMachineCal + weightsCal) - proteinShakeCal);

        if (totalGym >= 50 ) {
            System.out.println("Well done you have burned more than 50 calories whilst drinking protein shake");
        } else if (totalGym < 50 ) {
            System.out.println("Whats the bloody point of drinking protein if your putting the calories back on fatty: " + totalGym + " calories is how much you lost");
        }

        int gymAndTotal = actualIntake - totalGym;
        System.out.println("What you ate, plus minusing your workout along with the protein you consumed " + gymAndTotal);

        return totalGym;
    }

    public static void testingMeth (int actualIntake) {
        System.out.println(actualIntake);



    }

}
//Take calories in then calculate BMR and compare, return value
```

So I am currently learning java, just learning and making random calorie deficit and BMR program. I created a new method called:

```
public static int testingMeth(actualIntake) {
    System.out.println(actualIntake);
}
```

The issue is when i try to call the method after the gym method, it creates an error.

```
    gym (30,40,50,100, actualIntake);
}
testingMeth(actualIntake);
```

If i was to delete the gym method from the main method, all my other methods has errors. I do not necessarily need a solution for this program but rather why am i receiving these errors? Just want to learn and improve! Thanks.

In other words, I can call the testingMeth before the Gym method and it works fine, but why not after the gym method? and if i get rid of the gym method, multiple errors occur amongst the other methods within the program?

Comment: *"why am i receiving these errors"* - Can you edit the question to include the details of the errors you are seeing?

Comment: `testingMeth(actualIntake);` is outside of the `main` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see below code, i am able to run both method in any sequence and it's working fine as well.

You need to go through with [**`basics of method declaration and method call`**](https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/methods-and-method-declaration-in-java/).

It will help you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //making values easier to change and also create global variables for gym comparison

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many calories did you consume today?>> ");
        int actualIntake = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is your BMR?>> ");
        int BMR = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();

        //this method is what is expected with deficit
        calorieCalculation(actualIntake, BMR);
        //this is what you actually ate
        testingMeth(actualIntake);
        actualCalories(actualIntake, BMR);
        //gym with protein
        gym(30, 40, 50, 100, actualIntake);
    }

    //testing method


    //What the user should be following
    public static int calorieCalculation(int actualIntake, int BMR) {
        int calorieDifference = BMR - actualIntake;

        if (calorieDifference <= 0) {
            calorieDifference = Math.abs(BMR - actualIntake);
            System.out.println("You have went over your deficit, well done fatty = " + calorieDifference);
        } else if (calorieDifference >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Expected calorie deficit should be " + calorieDifference);
        }

        return calorieDifference;
    }

    //What the user actually did
    public static int actualCalories(int actualIntake, int BMR) {

        int deficitCalculation = actualIntake - BMR;
        if (actualIntake > BMR) {
            System.out.println("You fat lard stop overeating you dumbass, " + "failed deficit of over " + deficitCalculation + " Calories.");

        } else if (actualIntake < BMR) {
            System.out.println("Well done you created a deficit of " + deficitCalculation + " keep her going keep her movin.");
        }
        return deficitCalculation;
    }

    //How much did you burn in the gym
    public static int gym(int treadMillCal, int rowingMachineCal, int weightsCal, int proteinShakeCal, int actualIntake) {

        int totalGym = ((treadMillCal + rowingMachineCal + weightsCal) - proteinShakeCal);

        if (totalGym >= 50) {
            System.out.println("Well done you have burned more than 50 calories whilst drinking protein shake");
        } else if (totalGym < 50) {
            System.out.println("Whats the bloody point of drinking protein if your putting the calories back on fatty: " + totalGym + " calories is how much you lost");
        }

        int gymAndTotal = actualIntake - totalGym;
        System.out.println("What you ate, plus minusing your workout along with the protein you consumed " + gymAndTotal);

        return totalGym;
    }

    public static void testingMeth(int actualIntake) {
        System.out.println(actualIntake);
    }

}
```

You need to understand for **`every opening braces of class/method/switch-case/or condition must have closing braces.`**

In your case you are try to call some method after closing braces of class, so those elements are not part of your class and that's why it's throwing an error.

Comment: *those elements are not part of your class* Do you mean that they're not part of the method? Also, I already pointed that out in the comments. Since this is effectively a typo, the correct thing to do is comment and vote to close as a typo.